# Revit Get Point(X,Y,Z) from Cad

Tags: c#, api, coordinates, cad, revit

I'm trying to get some (XY) coordinates points and rotation from an imported CAD inside Revit , but it only works right if the CAD file was never moved/rotated , this means that the Revit API get the internal coordinates of the CAD regardless of the CAD position in Revit.

now when i try the same exercise but with "Dynamo" the coordinates are right even if the CAD was moved/ Rotated

So how to make this right?

```
        GeometryElement geoElement = cad.get_Geometry(new Options());

        foreach (GeometryObject geoObject in geoElement)
        {
            GeometryInstance instance = geoObject as GeometryInstance;
            if (null != instance)
            {
                foreach (GeometryObject instObj in instance.SymbolGeometry)
                {
                    if (instObj is GeometryInstance) 
                    {
                        GeometryInstance gi_block = instObj as GeometryInstance;
                        Transform transform = gi_block.Transform;

                        XYZ origin =  transform.Origin; // coordinates
                        TaskDialog.Show("xx", origin.ToString());

                        XYZ vectorTran = transform.OfVector(transform.BasisX.Normalize());
                        double rot = transform.BasisX.AngleOnPlaneTo(vectorTran, transform.BasisZ.Normalize()); // angle in radians

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Dynamo is automatically adjusting for the Revit project location, rotation to north, and other global coordinate transformation settings.

The discussion of [Real-World Concrete Corner Coordinates](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/real-world-concrete-corner-coordinates.html) includes a description of [Transforming Revit Model Coordinates to the Real World](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/real-world-concrete-corner-coordinates.html#4) that you might be able to apply.

Check out the resulting [Structural Concrete Setout Point Add-in](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/08/structural-concrete-setout-point-add-in.html), now alive on GitHub in the [SetoutPoints repository](https://github.com/jeremytammik/SetoutPoints).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first of all explore the [ProjectLocation](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/1249d5fa-74f3-cf64-0a63-7ab370b67a5c.htm) associated with your import instance. You can use [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) to do so.